# how to display this dynamic table by default?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code for dynamic HTML, but i cannot display this by default, the table is being displayed when I select the option,
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DYCm/

HTML:

```
       <tr>
  <th>Number of Models:<title="Number of Models"></th>

  <td><select id="numbermodels" name="numbermodels" autocomplete="off" onchange="buildTable(this.value);" >

  <option value="1" >1</option >
  <option value="2" >2</option >
  <option selected="selected" value="3" >3</option >
  <option value="4" >4</option >
  <option value="5" >5</option >
  <option value="6">6</option >
  </select></td>
  </tr>

<table id="contentTable" border="1" name="contentTable">
    <!-- Fill table programmatically -->
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
      function buildTable(val)
     {
var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
var j=val;
var rows = [];
var cells = [];

   while (myTable.hasChildNodes()) {
    myTable.removeChild(myTable.lastChild);
}


for( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
{
    rows[i] = myTable.insertRow(i);
    if(i%3==2)rows[i];
    cells[i] = [];

    for( var x = 0; x < j ; x++ )
    {
        cells[i][x] =document.createElement((x==0)?"th":"td");
        cells[i][x].innerHTML = (x==0)?"<input id=t  name=t[] size=3>":"<input id=t1 name=t1[] size=3>";
        rows[rows.length - 1].appendChild(cells[i][x]);
    }
}

  }
buildTable();
```

I tried giving onload in place of onchange, but when I give this, the table is not being generated, can someone tell me how to display this table by default ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing in the value to the function so `val` is undefined.

```
var sel = document.getElementById("numbermodels");
var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
buildTable(value);
```

This assumes that the script is loaded after the select and div are loaded on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/VC3uM/

Comment: the above solution is working in jsfiddle, but when i try it in my browser i.e. firefox, it is not working, i am having the same problem, the table is generated only after i select the option, not by default, what could be the reason ?

Comment: @Sachin Because you are not running it onload or after the element is rendered on the page.

Comment: are you saying, i need to change the onchange event to onload, or is it not possible to achieve on a browser, please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function createTable(){
    var sel = document.getElementById("numbermodels");
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    buildTable(value);
}

<td><select id="numbermodels" name="numbermodels" autocomplete="off" onchange="createTable();" >
```